How to save using ajax and confirm after clicking "ok" Django
I want to make it so that when a person wants to send a form to the submit button, they are asked if there is an intersection of dates in the database via ajax, and only when they agree to add it anyway, they will save it in the database and redirect to another page, so far it has been implemented so that an alert appears.
Komandirov_add.html
    <form method="post" id="contactForm">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {% if form.warnings %}
            <div class="rounded p-2 mt-2 bg-warning">
                <ul>
                    {% for warning in form.warnings %}
                        <li><b>{{ warning.message }}:</b> {{ warning.description }}</li>
                    {% endfor %}
                </ul>
            </div>
        {% endif %}
        <div style="display: flex;flex-wrap: wrap;">
            {{ form.NumberKU.label_tag }}{{ form.NumberKU }}
            {% if form.NumberKU.errors %}
                <div class="error">{{ form.NumberKU.errors }}</div>
            {% endif %}
        </div>
<input id='d' type="submit" onclick="reload_page(); return false;" value="Сохранить">


    </form>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {

          
            $('#contactForm').submit(function () {
                $.ajaxSetup({
                    headers: {
                        "X-CSRFToken": document.querySelector('[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').value,
                    }
                });
           
                $.ajax({
                    data: $(this).serialize(),
                    url: "{% url 'prikaz:komandirov_add' human.pk %}",
                    type: $(this).attr('method'),
                  
                    success: function (response) {

                        console.log(response.f)
                        if (response.f == 'f') {
                            alert('dd');
                            window.location.href = "{% url 'prikaz:komandirov' human.pk %}";
                        } else{
                             window.location.href = "{% url 'prikaz:komandirov' human.pk %}";
                        }
                    },
                    
                });
                return false;
            });
        })

    </script>

urls.py
urlpatterns = [

    path('human/<int:id>/komandirov/komandirov_add/', views.KomandirovAdd.as_view(), name='komandirov_add'),
]

views.py
class KomandirovAdd(FormView):  
    form_class = KomandirovForm
    template_name = 'prikaz/block_content/Komandirov_add.html'

    # context_object_name = 'form'

    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

        return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['human'] = Privatedata.objects.get(id=self.kwargs['id'])


        return context

    def form_valid(self, form):
        print(form.cleaned_data)
        addindb = form.save(commit=False)
        addindb.People = Privatedata.objects.get(id=self.kwargs['id'])
        addindb.save()
        overlapping_records = Otpysk.objects.filter(
            Q(DateUbitie__range=(form.cleaned_data['DateUbitie'], form.cleaned_data['DataPredpol'])) & Q(
                DataPredpol__range=(form.cleaned_data['DateUbitie'], form.cleaned_data['DataPredpol'])))
        if len(overlapping_records) > 0:
            return JsonResponse({'f':'f'})
        else:
            return JsonResponse({'f':'d'})
    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse_lazy("prikaz:komandirov", args=[self.kwargs['id']])



Just to be clear, so you want to check the data the user just entered into the form, against what is already stored on the server - before the new data actually gets saved? Well then you will either have to store the data into a session on first submission, so that after the user's confirmation you can then send another request, that signals to your server-side logic "save this session data into the database now" - or you will have to send the same data again with a second request. Only in handling the response of that second request must you redirect the client to the following page then.

Thank you very much for the idea, but won't it be possible to process everything in one request?

Checking for "an intersection of dates in the database" will require that you send the data to the server - unless you wanted to transport all data to the client first, so that it could make this decision on its own (but then you risk running into discrepancies, because the data could already have been modified on the server in the meantime.) But before you made this request, you won't know if you need to ask the user for confirmation.
